# Indian Passport with F1 visa not stamped upon entry to the US(I-94 is up to date). Will it be a problem when I apply for H1B?

Tags: usa, immigration, student-visa, h1-visa

I recently entered the US after my vacation in India. My port of entry was Boston and I live in Portland, OR. After reaching home, I noticed that I am missing the entry US stamp. I am currently in the process of applying for H1B. I am supposed to submit all the pages of passport. Will it be a problem for my H1B application ? I am not sure if I can get a deferred inspection in Portland

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's a problem. They don't always put entry stamps on passports (e.g. if you go through an automated kiosk), and people sometimes lose passports so could no longer have the entry stamp. It's the I-94 that is authoritative. If the I-94 shows that you were admitted into F1 status at the date and place that you entered, that should be enough.